# No converter registered for type

Tags: converters, pomm

For the same case, i have an another error :

No converter registered for type 'public.group',

I have, user, group and user_group tables.

```
    $sql = <<<SQL
        SELECT :projection
        FROM "user"
        LEFT JOIN user_group ON "user".id=user_group.user_id
        LEFT JOIN "group" ON "group".id=user_group.group_id
        WHERE "user".id = $*
        GROUP BY "user".id
```

SQL;

```
    $projection = $this->createProjection()
        ->setField('groups', 'array_agg("group") AS groups', 'public.group[]')
    ;
    $sql = strtr($sql, [':projection' => (string) $projection->formatFields('"user"')]);

    return $this->query($sql, [1], $projection);
```

In services.yaml :

```
App\Infrastructure\Model\MyDB\PublicSchema\GroupModel:
    tags: [pomm.model]

App\Infrastructure\Model\MyDB\PublicSchema\UserGroupModel:
    tags: [pomm.model]

App\Infrastructure\Model\MyDB\PublicSchema\UserModel:
    tags: [pomm.model]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ovoid having to register a converter for each table of the database, converters are loaded when tables model classes are loaded.

Adding the following line at the beginning of your method should resolve your problem:

```
$groupModel = $this->getSession()->getModel(GroupModel::class);
```

This also gives you the ability not to deal with the `group` relation name as it is stored in the structure that comes with the model.